# PHP file won't copy

Tags: php, mysql, database, copy

I have a PHP script to sign up people as a member. After inserting their data in the database, a folder is created inside the 'user' folder with their name ($u).
After creating the file, I want to copy the image thumbnail.png from the folder mydomain/img/thumbnail.png to mydomain/user/$u/dummypic.png. The signup process is successful and I get no error messages. But when I look in the created folder, the file is not copied there, it's empty.

Anyone who can see what's wrong with the code I have?

```
// xxx code of inserting in DB xxx

  // Create directory(folder) and copy the dummy avatar picture
if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
    mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
    copy('img/dummypic.png', 'user/$u/dummypic.png');
}
```

Comment: Privileges problem probably. Check if php user can read first at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $u in double quotes "". Like below:

```
copy('img/dummypic.png', "user/$u/dummypic.png");
```

Comment: This did the trick! That I didn't see that myself.. Anyway, thanks for the help man!